# How to stop ReverseProxy from proxying request

Tags: http, go, reverse-proxy

Is there any way to prevent `httputil.ReverseProxy` from sending an incoming request to the target server? For example, if I have a cache and I can respond to the client using only local data. Or after validation, I want to return an error to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `httputil.ReverseProxy` has a single exported method, [`ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request)`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy.ServeHTTP) which makes it implement the [`net/http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) interface.

So basically at a place you're now using an vanilla `httputil.ReverseProxy` instance, instead use an instance of your custom type which implements `net/http.Handler` as well, keeps a pointer to an instance of `httputil.ReverseProxy`, and either processes the request itself or calls out to that `ReverseProxy` instance's `ServeHTTP`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to wrap the `http.DefaultTransport` with a cache that can either use the cache based on the request or fallback on the `http.DefaultTransport`.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)

var _ http.RoundTripper = &CachingTransport{}

type CachingTransport struct {
    // put your cache here  
}

func (c *CachingTransport) RoundTrip(request *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    // determine whether to use the cache and return, or use the default transport
    return http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(request)
}

func main() {
    _ = httputil.ReverseProxy{
        Transport: &CachingTransport{},
    }
}
```